# React Native TypeError: React.createClass is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, build

**Our code is failing to build showing the below error. We have not used createClass anywhere. Why is this still showing?**

yarn test
yarn run v1.7.0
$ jest
 FAIL  ./App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: React.createClass is not a function

> 1 | import React, { Component } from 'react';
  2 | import {
  3 |   StyleSheet,
  4 |   Text,

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-sleek-loading-indicator/loader.js:1:333)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-sleek-loading-indicator/index.js:1:288)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/Login.js:1:2238)
```

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        18.691s
Ran all test suites.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

our Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  Platform,
  AsyncStorage
} from 'react-native';
```